# Public key in fully homomorphic encryption over the integers

Tags: homomorphic-encryption

I'm reading [“Fully Homomorphic Encryption over the Integers”](https://eprint.iacr.org/2009/616.pdf) by van Dijk et al.

I wonder why $x_0$, which is a component of the public key, should be an odd number?

Comment: What happens if you set it even?

Comment: Thanks for giving me a hint. (even number mod even number) is always even number and (odd number mod even number) is always odd number. If m=0, the result of modular $x_0$ will be always even number. If m=1, the result will be odd number. So $x_0$ should be a odd number.

Comment: @JongHyunKim, you could post that as an answer, so if someone else arrives here wondering about it, they can easily find it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(even number mod even number) is always even number and (odd number mod even number) is always odd number. If $m=0$, the result of modular $x_0$ will be always even number. If $m=1$, the result will be odd number. So $x_0$ should be a odd number.